# Spark-version-info.properties not found in jenkins

Tags: java, apache-spark, maven-3, jenkins-plugins, sparkcore

I am developing a plugin which uses *spark-core lib*. it is ok when I run it as java application but when I run the plugin in Jenkins it show an error which says that

```
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.spark.package$.<init>(package.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.package$.<clinit>(package.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkContext.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkContext.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.logInfo(Logging.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.logInfo(SparkContext.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2275)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$8.apply(SparkSession.scala:831)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$8.apply(SparkSession.scala:823)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:823)
    at com.plugin.goettingen_plugin.HelloWorldBuilder.perform(HelloWorldBuilder.java:88)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:75)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:785)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:205)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:162)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:537)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:408)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Error while locating file spark-version-info.properties
    at org.apache.spark.package$SparkBuildInfo$.liftedTree1$1(package.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.package$SparkBuildInfo$.<init>(package.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.package$SparkBuildInfo$.<clinit>(package.scala)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:434)
    at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:353)
    at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:341)
    at org.apache.spark.package$SparkBuildInfo$.liftedTree1$1(package.scala:64)
    ... 25 more
```

I am using the following code to start a spark session:

```
SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().appName("DP-App").master("local[2]").getOrCreate();
```

The *spark-core* lib searches the file by a class named as package.java by the following code which returns null:

```
InputStream resourceStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("spark-version-info.properties");
```

Since the *spark-version-info.properties* was present inside *spark-core lib*, I tried to shift the file to Web-INF but still it failed to load the file.
Is there any alternative way to load the file and bypass the above code which is inside the library?

My dependencies are:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>credentials</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 4):

You are missing `spark-version-info.properties` file.

So just create one under `./core/target/extra-resources`

```
λ ~/workspace/big_data/spark/ master* ./build/spark-build-info ./core/target/extra-resources 2.1.1
λ ~/workspace/big_data/spark/ master* cat ./core/target/extra-resources/spark-version-info.properties
version=2.1.1
user=chanhle
revision=dec9aa3b37c01454065a4d8899859991f43d4c66
branch=master
date=2017-06-07T15:12:48Z
url=https://github.com/apache/spark
```

I am experiencing the same problem too when debugging Spark on IntelliJ.

Comment: the problem was with the ContextLoader class of java. It was not able to detect the path when the plug was run inside Jenkins on a browser.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem by using worksheets in IntelliJ IDE. Solved it by disabling "Run worksheet in the compiler process"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found that if you load Apache Spark through a classloader that is different than the `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` value, then this version file will not be found.
If you are doing custom classloading, then you should make sure that you set the classloader that Spark was loaded through using the `Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(myCustomLoader)` call. This solved the problem for me.